# how to fix ERROR: Spider error processing GET url

Tags: python, parsing, request, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm scraping e-commerce site, and scraping multiple categories of it but some of them producing results but some of links got ERROR: Spider error processing... please help me how to sort it...

[this is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZuKO.png)

[this is code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hce1x.png)

[this is the error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDZLN.png)

Comment: Please try to put the minimum code that helps to solve your problem alongside with your question, rather than posting images of the code.

Comment: they didnt let me upload my code... btw im scraping a site with request different urls of site with meta "categories" according to url... but some of return results and some of give processing error... please check the code from images

Comment: Samsung_Tablets = response.urljoin("prices/tablets/samsung")
        yield scrapy.Request(Samsung_Tablets, callback = self.parse_products, meta = {'category' : 'Tablets','subcategory' : 'Samsung', 'brand': 'Samsung'}, dont_filter=True)

Comment: INFO: Crawled 27 pages (at 14 pages/min), scraped 282 items (at 194 items/min)
2019-04-18 21:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.shophive.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?p=2&q=+mobile+phones+onepl> (referer: http://www.shophive.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=+mobile+phones+onepl)
2019-04-18 21:31:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.shophive.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?p=2&q=+mobile+phones+onepl> (referer: http://www.shophive.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=+mobile+phones+onepl)

Comment: Please edit the question and supply the complete minimal code together with any relevant output directly in the text, not as images hosted on other services.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read this guide: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error data from console error occures on urls with p argument `?p=2` - it means that your scraper doesn't process second pages of specific seacrch.
It looks like your application doesn't transfer metadata to next requests.

`parse_products` method of your spider require meta datafrom `parse` method.
I suppose that your `parse_products` code responsible to search results pagination looks like this:

```
yield Request(next_url,callback=self.parse_products)
```

If its true your application will be unable to read metadata and raise error like from your console.
In this case you need to add meta argument to nextpage request in your `parse_products` mehtod:

```
yield Request(next_url, meta = response.meta,callback=self.parse_products)
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I got error, it was in link... thanks for your time